# Subsequence proof and examples

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I'm trying to show the following:

1. Proposition 1: If a sequence $(a_{n}) \rightarrow a$ then every
   subsequence of that sequence will converge to $a$
2. Proposition 2: Assume we have a sequence $(a_{n})$ and we want to show it converges. Further, assume that the subsequences $(a_{2n}), (a_{2n+1})$ both converge to $a$, then $(a_{n})\rightarrow a$.
3. Calculate the first three terms of subsequences: $(a_{n+4}), (a_{2^{n}})$ given that $(a_{n}) = (n^{2})$.

Attempt at Proposition 1:

Suppose that $(a_{n}) \rightarrow a$. Let $n_{i}$ denote an increasing sequence of the natural numbers and consider the corresponding subsequence of the original sequence. By definition, there exists a natural number $N$ such that we have, for any $\epsilon > 0, |a_{n}-a|< \epsilon$ for $n > N$.

Then for the subsequence $(a_{n_{i}})$ as long as $i > N$ we have $|a_{n_{i}} - a| < \epsilon$. Proving the result.

Attempt at Proposition 2:

Suppose that $(a_{n})$ is such that $(a_{2n})$ and $(a_{2n+1})$ converge to $a$. Let $\epsilon > 0$, by assumption $|a_{2n}-a|< \epsilon$ for a sufficiently large $N_{1}$, and similarly, $|a_{2n+1}-a|< \epsilon$, for $n > N_{2}$. Choosing an $n$ such that $n>N$, where $N=\max\{N_{1},N_{2}\}$ we have that $(a_{n}) \rightarrow a$. Since no matter if we take $n$ to be odd or even, $|a_{n} - a| <\epsilon$, because $a_{n}$ will belong to the even or odd subsequence.

Attempt at calculation:

$(a_{n}) = (n^{2})$, having terms: $1,4,9$
$(a_{n+4})$ has terms $25,36,49$
$(a_{2^{n}})$ has terms $4, 16,64$

Answer (score 1):

Could be better.

**Proposition 1**: Second bit, what's $n$? What you're varying is $i$. Note that since $(n_i)$ is necessarily strictly increasing we have $n_i \ge i$ for all $i \in \mathbb N$. With that in mind, you can pick a suitable $N$ to satisfy your claim.

**Proposition 2**: It would be clearer here if you use separate $N$s for each inequality, ie. $N_1$ and $N_2$, then picking the largest of these so that both inequalities hold for $n > N = \max\{N_1,N_2\}$. I'm not quite sure what you're arguing for the last bit of that proposition. It seems you're just restating $(a_{2n}) \to a$ and $(a_{2 n + 1}) \to a$? I think you might have the right idea though. Keep in mind what it means for $(a_n) \to a$, and link it with the two inequalities you just found to work for $n > N$.

Calculations at the end are fine.

Comment: The second bit of proposition one was a typo. I meant $i$ not $n$ (i will edit it). Proposition two, agreed it is clearer taking the $\max\{N_{1},N_{2}\}$. The last part of Proposition two, I'll try and make clearer.